# Laravel 8: Sessions get cleared even if stored in database

Tags: php, session, laravel-8

I'm trying to save sessions in files but have an issue. When created, I can access it and get it's value in the same file (controller). Then I call an API endpoint which tries to get the value of that session (in another file which is a service) but I found out that all sessions get cleared. I changed the storage to `database` and I can check the id of the session and it's already there in `sessions` table but when I call the API endpoint which fetches that session value in the service, I get nothing. Here's how I set the session in the controller

```
session(['dir_unique_id' => $dir_unique_id]);
```

I also tried

```
Session::put('dir_unique_id', $dir_unique_id);
```

I get the value in a service like this

```
Session::get('dir_unique_id')
```

But I get nothing in the service though I get the correct value in the controller after saving the session. So why sessions get destroyed suddenly or why value get cleared though it's stored in the `sessions` table and how to fix it?

**[Update]**

Now when I call `session()->all()` I get only 1 session and all other sessions got cleared!

Comment: `I call the API endpoint which fetches that session value in the service` - How would this API know which session to open/retrieve the data from?

Comment: `Session::get('dir_unique_id')`

Comment: That is the variable name you've stored in the session on the client's side or is this also the session id?

Comment: Now in the API (the service) I call `session()->all()` and get only 1 session `_token`

Comment: That's the session key name not the id

Comment: That's what I was suggesting. You need to provide the session id in order to open the correct file/record. Furthermore `session()->all()` doesn't return all the (active) sessions, it return all the data stored in a session

Comment: even if I managed to get the value by session id, how can I get the session id in the second API request as I don't know it and depend on getting the value by session key name?

Comment: You can retrieve the session id of the client by `session()->getId()`, this value you can send to your API, maybe you could add this value in a custom header, making it retrievable for your API